# python Popen sub processing error in Macs

Tags: python-3.x, image, video, subprocess, popen

'''
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
'''
p = Popen(
'''
args=['ffmpeg','-y', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-vcodec', 'png', '-r',
'''
str(fps), '-i', '-', '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-r', str(fps), '-pix_fmt',
'''
yuv420p', '-crf', '17', '-preset', 'veryslow', 'video.mp4'],
'''
stdin=PIPE,
'''
)
'''
print(p.stdin)
'''
for im in tqdm(frames):
'''
im.save(p.stdin, 'PNG')
'''
p.stdin.close()

'''
print("El vídeo está siendo ahora comprimido, espera...")
'''
p.wait()
'''

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

As long as `im` is an `Image` object, the code should work.

Here is a self contained code sample:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Fill tqdm list with some data - this is an example (not part of the code)
################################################################################
frames = []
for i in range(100):
    img = np.full((240, 320, 3), i+1, np.uint8)
    img[0:i, 0:i, :] = (i*100 % 255, i*200 % 255, i*300 % 255)
    im = Image.fromarray(img)  # Convert NumPy array to PIL image object
    frames.append(im)  # Append the image to the list
################################################################################


fps = 10
    
p = Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-vcodec', 'png', '-r', str(fps), '-i', '-', '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-r', str(fps), '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-crf', '17', '-preset', 'veryslow', 'video.mp4'], stdin=PIPE)
    
print(p.stdin)
    
for im in tqdm(frames):
    im.save(p.stdin, 'PNG')

p.stdin.close()

print("El vídeo está siendo ahora comprimido, espera...")
p.wait()
```